# wrong type for column names in sort_values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Very simple issue for a non-newbie I'm sure.
`df.sort_values(df.columns.values,axis=0,na_position="first")` does not work.
`df.sort_values([0,1,2,3],axis=0,na_position="first")` does.

`df.columns.values` : `array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int64)`

What am I doing wrong ? Should I convert the Numpy array into a regular array ? If yes how do I do that ?

Comment: If you are doing something wrong, the first item on that list is not showing your data. Please see how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so that folks here can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use tolist() to convert it to list before using in sort_values(), as:

```
df.sort_values(df.columns.values.tolist(),axis=0,na_position="first")
```